# Following symbolic links in QGIS to load data on Linux?

Tags: qgis, qgis-2, esri-grid-format

Can QGIS 2.4 follow Linux soft links?

I want to add a number of raster layers from a store of NED30m elevation data, and thought I'd do it by creating a collection of softlinks in one directory to the elevation files nested in the store.

However, when I try to add a layer from one of the links, QGIS 2.4 complains:

> Raster layer: *somepath*/elev_ned30m_links/n46w105.adf is not a supported 
>   raster data source

However, `n46w105.adf` is the result of a linux `ln -s` command:

> ln -s /Mapstore/ned30m/grid/n46w105_1/w001001.adf

QGIS will open `w001001.adf` just fine if approached directly, but that means digging down into each tile's directory structure, while the softlinks can be created programmatically with a script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes QGIS can follow symbolic links.

However, an ArcGIS Grid coverage can't be linked like that, the raster data is not just the .adf file, it is a directory of related files stored in a parent directory (workspace) with an INFO directory and you can not change either the directory structure or the .adf filename (both of which you did with the ln -s command), see [format description](http://www.digitalpreservation.gov/formats/fdd/fdd000281.shtml):

[image: structure]

However, you have another option...

Use your script to create VRT headers pointing to the Grid .adf files and store them in a single directory. Replace the bit in your script that does the `ln -s ...` with

```
gdal_translate -of VRT /absolute/path/to/wNNNN.adf /absolute/path/to/vrt/directory/someraster.vrt
```

Alternatively, if you wish to mosaic the GRIDS, create a textfile with the paths of all the GRIDs (either /path/to/GRID folder path or /path/to/GRID/w001001.adf file path) and then use

```
gdalbuildvrt -input_file_list /path/to/gridlist.txt your_new_mosaic.vrt
```

Comment: Ah, I had been lulled into a misunderstanding by QGIS' accepting me just finding and clicking the, one, adf file. (what is with not being able to enter a carriage-return??)  Anyway, I've used a VRT only one prior time (I think), to unify a whole host of individually loaded ned tiles in order to treat them as a single unit for purposes of doing a StretchToMinMax. (whoops, I hit Return again...) Thanks, Luke (fwiw, I wanted this to be nicely formatted with whitespa[CR]

Comment: @quagmire comment fields are very limited, probably intentionally. Have a look at the VRT tutorial http://www.gdal.org/gdal_vrttut.html

Comment: That worked a treat!  However, in following up on my recollection about how to treat the multiples as one, I found a reference to a capability of gdal_translate or gdal_warp to recombine multiple .vrts into a single image. It would be most perfect if I could output a single image from all the tiles, or alternatively, load all the tiles as a single virtual image. It might appear from this comment that I ignored your link, but I did visit...

Comment: @quagmire gdalbuildvrt http://www.gdal.org/gdalbuildvrt.html

Comment: Simple perfection. After creating the individual .vrts as you suggest, I am dumbfounded to find they go together as easily as: % gdalbuildvrt gdalbuildvrt_out.tif n??w???.vrt

Comment: If you asked the right question ;), you could have skipped the adf->individual vrt step and just used gdalbuildvrt to mosiac the adf files. `gdalbuildvrt -input_file_list adflist.txt gdalbuildvrt_out.vrt`. Note that the output is a VRT not a tiff.